# How to disable an AutoKey script while in a specific program?

Tags: regular-expression, keyboard-shortcuts

This is a regular expression question.

I use AutoKey on Debian to execute custom commands with hotkeys, such as <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to toggle Nautilus.

But sometimes I run a VM in VirtualBox and AutoKey is toggling my host Nautilus while in the VM guest (hijacking it) which I don't want.

AutoKey has a 'Window Filter' in each script's settings where you can, with a regular expression, restrict what window class or title to enable the script with.

What I need then is a regex to express 'any window class except **VirtualBox**'.

AutoKey is python-based, so that may be its type of regex to use.

What regular expression will work in AutoKey to disable a script on just one window class?

(There is some discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autokey-users/UVDXuND4Ep4) with regex examples that demonstrably don't work.)

Answer (score 4):

In this case, use this window filter which filters out VirtualBox:

```
^((?!VirtualBox).)*$
```

Comment: relevant: https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/161

Comment: Was this tested does this work? I thought that in general it was very difficult to make these exceptions in AutoKey since they made the stupid choice that it matches if either the Title or the Class mathces which means you can only write an regex to exclude it if 1.) there some part that is universal to both the class and the tittle which can often be completely different things and 2.) this universal part must not be so universal that it also occurs in other programs where you do want the script to apply.